# Find coordinates(pixels) in an RGB image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have some data with (x,y) values, these should represent certain pixels in my image. For example the following data:

```
            x           y
0  487.187726   38.631769
1  488.574303   84.000148
2   75.635379   51.267148
3   203.34296   73.830325
4  223.198556   79.245487
5  230.870036  115.797834
6  141.068592  169.949458
7  122.115523  153.703971
8   38.631769  128.433213
9  316.624767  127.530686
```

Here a dump in case someone would like to use it:

```
{'x': {0: 487.1877256317687, 1: 488.5743028961937, 2: 75.6353790613718, 3: 203.34296028880857, 4: 223.1985559566786, 5: 230.87003610108297, 6: 141.0685920577617, 7: 122.11552346570392, 8: 38.63176895306856, 9: 316.62476684835565}, 'y': {0: 38.63176895306856, 1: 84.0001478379886, 2: 51.267148014440465, 3: 73.83032490974733, 4: 79.24548736462097, 5: 115.79783393501808, 6: 169.9494584837545, 7: 153.7039711191336, 8: 128.4332129963899, 9: 127.53068592057764}}
```

I also have this RGB image:

[image]

I would like to access the pixels of this image that have this coordinates (x,y). The origin (0,0) corresponds to the upper-left part of the image and it increases as y goes down the image and x goes to the right of the image. I have been given float numbers, I'm not sure if it's possible to interpolate (x,y) with a float number or only integers though.

The image shape is (500,500,3):

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('img1.bmp')
print(img.shape)
(500,500,3)
```

Comment: I think it depends what you are trying to do. For the first point, you could take the range 482..492 in x, and 33..43 in y and use `cv2.resize()` to make it 100-1000 times bigger using all the different interpolation methods available to see what sort of values you will get at the fractional (float) positions and see how that relates to what you need. Note that you are more or less obliged to use *"Nearest Neighbour"* if you want to avoid introducing new colours into the image.

Comment: Just use Numpy to print your values for the given x,y.  `print(image[y:y+1, x:x+1])`

Comment: It's not possible to interpolate (x, y) with a float number. You could just convert float to integer by flooring each (x, y) coordinates into integer then you can access each pixel directly with `image[x, y]`

Comment: Nathancy is correct. Sorry, I forgot to add the int().  `print(image[int(y):int(y)+1, int(x):int(x)+1])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the x,y as cols, rows indexes to numpy array indexing as follows

```py
import numpy as np

dict_xy = {'x': {0: 487.1877256317687, 1: 488.5743028961937, 2: 75.6353790613718, 3: 203.34296028880857, 4: 223.1985559566786, 5: 230.87003610108297, 6: 141.0685920577617, 7: 122.11552346570392, 8: 38.63176895306856, 9: 316.62476684835565}, 'y': {0: 38.63176895306856, 1: 84.0001478379886, 2: 51.267148014440465, 3: 73.83032490974733, 4: 79.24548736462097, 5: 115.79783393501808, 6: 169.9494584837545, 7: 153.7039711191336, 8: 128.4332129963899, 9: 127.53068592057764}}
npx, npy = np.array(list(dict_xy['x'].values())).astype(int), np.array(list(dict_xy['y'].values())).astype(int)

# test image creation
np.random.seed(42)
img = np.random.randint(0,high=256,size=(500,500,3))
#print (img)

img_select = img[npy,npx,:]
```